# Failing to merge html files in R

Tags: html, r, concatenation

So I have two html pages, `html_1.html` and `html_2.html` I I would like to stack them one on top of the other in R. How to do that?

example:

```
library(dygraphs)
m1 = dygraph(nhtemp, main = "New Haven Temperatures") %>% 
  dyRangeSelector(dateWindow = c("1920-01-01", "1960-01-01"))
m2 = dygraph(nhtemp, main = "New Haven Temperatures") %>% 
  dyRangeSelector(dateWindow = c("1920-01-01", "1960-01-01"))
library(htmltools)
save_html(m1, file = 'm1.html')
save_html(m2, file = 'm2.html')
##Now load and merge m1.html and m2.html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *simplest* way is to use an R markdown document:

````
---
title: ""
output: html_document
---
```{r echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
library(dygraphs)

dygraph(nhtemp, main = "New Haven Temperatures", elementId = "a") %>% 
  dyRangeSelector(dateWindow = c("1920-01-01", "1960-01-01"))

dygraph(nhtemp, main = "New Haven Temperatures", elementId = "b") %>% 
  dyRangeSelector(dateWindow = c("1920-01-01", "1960-01-01"))
```
````

That takes care of many complex things for you.

The *heavyweight* way is to build the page on your own without getting into the gnarly details of widget javascript dependencies:

```
library(dygraphs)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(htmltools)

w1 <- dygraph(nhtemp, main = "New Haven Temperatures", elementId = "a") %>% 
  dyRangeSelector(dateWindow = c("1920-01-01", "1960-01-01"))

w2 <- dygraph(nhtemp, main = "New Haven Temperatures", elementId = "b") %>% 
  dyRangeSelector(dateWindow = c("1920-01-01", "1960-01-01"))

saveWidget(w1, "w1.html")
saveWidget(w2, "w2.html")

w1_src <- sprintf("data:text/html;base64,%s", openssl::base64_encode(rawToChar(readBin("w1.html", "raw", file.size("w1.html")))))
w2_src <- sprintf("data:text/html;base64,%s", openssl::base64_encode(rawToChar(readBin("w2.html", "raw", file.size("w2.html")))))

tags$html(
  tags$body(
    tags$iframe(src=w1_src, seamless="", frameborder="0", allowtransparency="true", scrolling="no", style="width:100%;height:400px"),
    tags$iframe(src=w2_src, seamless="", frameborder="0", allowtransparency="true", scrolling="no", style="width:100%;height:400px")
  )
) %>% 
  save_html("bothwidgets.html")
```

You can't just `save_html()` a widget since they depend on components that get automagically incorporated for you. You need to use `iframe`s in the second approach unless you want to deal with widget dependency de-duplication and proper component inclusion for a lighter weight document on your own.

In this case, the difference isn't too bad, but still substantial. The first output file is 1.3MB the second is 2MB.

Note that you'll likely need to size the `iframe`s better than I did in a production environment.

Comment: Thanks, I really like your first solution. But how do you save your  first solution to an html file (the computations take a long time and I want to use the html file to showcase the results. I don't have time to run the .rmd each time)

Comment: `rmarkdown::render("whateverYouCalledTheFile.Rmd")` will save it to an HTML file.